# How to filter distinct data in CloudSearch:AWS?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I have a query in aws cloudsearch. I did the following things

1) Created domain

2) uploaded the data & created indexing

I have data fields like : `user_id, user_name, user_details`, etc

My objective is to get the grouped/distinct data of particular field & its total count. In Cloudsearch **Group by / Distinct** key words not supported. So, I went through the cloudsearch documentation & done it by adding `facet.user_id={}` in my query string.

But I need user_name field data along with user_id and count.** Please update me regarding this.

**Here is my full query :** `?q="Tamil Selvan"&facet.user_id={}`

**Here is my query result :**

```
{
    "status": {
        "rid": "isTcmOYp+AEKhpbc",
        "time-ms": 6
    },
    "hits": {
        "found": 986,
        "start": 0,
        "hit": []
    },
    "facets": {
        "user_id": {
            "buckets": [{
                "value": "5",
                "count": 213
            }, {
                "value": "182",
                "count": 197
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

**My expected result :**

```
{
    "status": {
        "rid": "isTcmOYp+AEKhpbc",
        "time-ms": 6
    },
    "hits": {
        "found": 986,
        "start": 0,
        "hit": []
    },
    "facets": {
        "user_id": {
            "buckets": [{
                "value": "5",
                "user_name":"Tamil Selvan",
                "count": 213
            }, {
                "value": "182",
                "user_name":"Tamil Selvi",
                "count": 197
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution would be to look up the `user_names` for the `user_id` facet values from your datastore (which CloudSearch is not, or at least should not be).

CloudSearch is a search solution; you shouldn't be trying to ask it which user_name belongs to some user_id, as that's a question for your data store.